# Sharing Silverlight and WPF Models with MVVM Light

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm-light

I have a Silverlight class library which is a model in my MVVM app. I am using MVVM Light. How easy is it reuse that model in a WPF app and use the MVVM Light framework. The framework has different dlls for WPF and Silverlight so I guess there is incompatability of sorts. I was wondering if anyone could talk me through the options. Cheers, Chris.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested option is to use the [Project Linker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921108%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx), this tool synchronizes code over multiple projects, allowing you to maintain a Silverlight and WPF dll with one codebase.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you mean model means data in WPF and Silverlight. If that is the case, you can expose the data using a Service. It can be any service like web service, WCF service or WCF RIA service. Since a service can be multi tenented you can have a Silverlight as well as WPF client accessing the same service.

If you are trying to share the ViewModels between Silverlight and WPF using MVVM light, I would suggest you have a look at the MIX 2011 video of the presentation by the creator of MVVMLight library [Laurent Bugnion](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/). This is called [Deep Dive MVVM](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2011/04/13/deep-dive-mvvm-samples-mix11-deepdivemvvm.aspx) and is a very good session. In short you can share ViewModels between WPF and Silverlight by adding the file from one project to another as a "LINK".

Hope this helps